# Cordova Build Version in XCode

Tags: ios, xml, xcode, cordova, phonegap-cli

I'm using Cordova 6.0. 
I'm developing for iOS.
I'm using XCode 7.3.

I have my widget specified like this config.xml:

```
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="2.0.0" ios-CFBundleVersion="2.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

For some reason when I run the `cordova prepare ios` command it sets the bundle and version in XCode to `0.0.1` instead of `2.0.0`.

How do I fix this so it sets the correct version number.

Comment: are you editing the config.xml on the root of the project? Or the one on platforms/ios?

Comment: In the root of the project.

Comment: which cordova-ios platform do you have? I can't reproduce your problem with cordova 6.1.0, cordova-ios 4.1.0

Comment: This has seemed to fix itself with a recent update and project refresh.